# Get contents of a file from another branch without checking it out

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-pull

I am trying to get the content of a file from another branch.
I am doing the following:

```
git checkout branchB some_specific_file.cc
```

The current branch stays unaffected. I suspect the reason is that even though I have done a `git pull` I have never checked out `branchB` locally.
Is there a way for this command to work if I have just done a `pull` in the repo but never actually checked out the other branch?
Is there something equilalent to:

```
git pull  
git checkout branchB  
git checkout branchA  
git checkout branchB some_specific_file.cc
```

without actually having to switch to branches so the last command works?

Comment: If you want the content of file `some_specific_file.cc` from branchB, just do `git show branchB:path/to/some_specific_file.cc`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### TL;DR

I think what you want is:

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout origin/branchB -- some_specific_file.cc
```

#### Background

The fundamental error you are making here is thinking that branches mean something. :-)  Or rather, that a *branch name* has some sort of global meaning—but it doesn't!

The `git pull` command is meant as a convenience operation: it first runs `git fetch`, then it runs a second Git command.  The default second command is normally `git merge`, but (a) you can change this and (b) there are some corner cases.  The reason this is supposedly (but not actually) convenient is that `git fetch` only *obtains new commits*.  It *does not affect any of your branches* (which are **yours**, they do not belong to some remote like `origin`!).

Typically, after you have obtained new commits from some remote like `origin`, you will want to *incorporate* (some of) those commits into (some of) your own branches.  To do that, you need a second Git command, such as `git merge` or `git rebase`.  There are many small issues here though, such as:

- How do you know whether to merge, rebase, or do something else entirely?
- What if you want to operate on *more than one* of your branches?

The `git pull` convenience command casts all of these aside and assures you that, no matter what `git fetch` did, you're 100% sure that an immediate `git xxx`—you fill in the `xxx` part *before* you fetch—is the right answer!  If it's not—which actually turns out to be *very often*, in my experience—then `git pull` is the wrong command.

#### What you're doing above

Your sequence of these two commands above:

```
git pull
git checkout branchB
```

will, if you do not yet *have* a `branchB`, *create* for yourself a *new* (local) branch name `branchB`, pointing to *the same* commit as your existing *remote-tracking name* `origin/branchB`.  Then:

```
git checkout branchA
```

gets you back on your (presumably existing) branchA, about which we have more to say in a moment.  The final command:

```
git checkout branchB -- some_specific_file.cc
```

then extracts that specific file from the commit identified by the name `branchB`.  (I added the `--` here—it's a good idea to use it by reflex, in case a file name resembles a `git checkout` option or branch name; `some_specific_file.cc` won't, so it's safe either way.)

#### git pull = git fetch + git merge

The `git fetch` step has your Git call up another Git, typically at the URL you have stored under the name `origin`.  Their Git lists *their* branch names, and which commit hash IDs go with those branch names.  Your Git then makes sure you have those commits, and once you do, sets up *your* `origin/*` names to *remember* those hash IDs.

The `origin/*` names are what I call *remote-tracking names;* Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names*.  They remember, for you, in your own Git repository, where the remote's branch names were, the last time your Git talked with their Git.

Hence, since `git pull` runs `git fetch`, this has the side effect of updating your remote-tracking names.  But there's a problem: `git pull`, in its effort to be convenient, *limits* the set of names that `git fetch` fetches.

Normally `git fetch` fetches *all* their branch names, updating *all* of your corresponding remote-tracking names.  When run from `git pull`, though, Git looks at your *current branch's* so-called *upstream* setting.  Typically the upstream of `master` is `origin/master`, the upstream of `branchA` is `origin/branchA`, and so on.  These are your names for their branches.  When `git pull` runs `git fetch`, it says: *only update this one remote-tracking name.*

**What this means in the end is that `git pull` while *not* on `branchB` won't update your `origin/branchB`, and that's (eventually) a big problem.**  You will need to reverse the order of the commands: check out `branchB` first, *then* pull.  (Or, better, *avoid* `git pull`, but hold on a moment.)

#### Creating a (local) branch

The `git checkout` command will switch you to some existing branch that you already have:

```
git checkout master
```

for instance will switch you to `master`, which you probably already have.  But if you *don't* have it yet, `git checkout` will scan your `origin/*` names—the remote-tracking (not-exactly-a-branch) names—to see if there's one that matches after taking away the `origin/` part.

If so, your Git will *create* a *new* local branch name that has the `origin/` version of itself as its "upstream".

#### `git merge` operates always and only on the *current branch*

The last step of `git pull` is normally to run `git merge`.  If you run:

```
git checkout branchB
git pull
```

this means that Git should:

- check out your existing `branchB`, or create it if necessary from `origin/branchB`;
- fetch and update `origin/branchB` (only);
- run `git merge` to update your current branch—`branchB`—using its upstream, `origin/branchB`, which `git fetch` just updated.

The merge step will then make your local branch `branchB` get updated.

So in general, you have to `git checkout branchB` *before* you `git pull` so as to make sure that `origin/branchB` is the (single) remote-tracking name that the `fetch` updates, and then your own local `branchB` is also updated.

#### You don't need that

But you don't need *any* of that for your task.  If you just run `git fetch`, which updates *all* your `origin/*` names, and then use `origin/branchB` to identify the commit that contains the version of `some_specific_file.cc` that you want, you're good.  Hence the final set of commands I suggest at the top.

Comment: So `git fetch` will download the new commits from all branches, so for `branchB` too but will not merge them and that is why using `origin/branchB` will give me the contents?

Comment: Yes. The `fetch` step downloads the commits *and* updates the *name* `origin/branchB`. Since that's not one of your (local) branches, none of your *branches* change, but the remote-tracking name `origin/branchB` now selects *their* latest `branchB` commit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer

Answer (score 3):

You can run `git fetch` to sync remote branches and then checkout the file directly from `origin/branchB`

```
git checkout origin/branchB some_specific_file.cc
```

to get contents of specific file from remote branch.
(assuming `origin` is the name of the remote)

Comment: The difference is in checking out frome remote branch. Git pull calls git merge which will only affect current branch.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout target_branch  -- file.cpp`

This really helps me, it saves me from checkout out the whole branch and then rebuild the project. By just checkout the file I needed. Unnessary rebuild is avoided. Thanks a lot!